# How to go from single View to spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I have a app that Im making and I need to transition from my single view application view to a GameScene. I added the GameViewController.swift, GameScene.swift and the GameScene.sks to my project. How do I segue from my view controller to my GameScene? Ive looked up examples but none of them help, any quick solutions would be great.

Here is the code Im using to go to my game.

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let gameView: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "miniGame") as! UINavigationController
self.present(gameView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but I get an error

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x2d73b00) to 'SKView' (0x1ba878c).
```

(lldb)

it pops the error on this line of code in my GameViewController

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
```

Comment: The GameViewController is just like any other view controller, just that it houses an SKView which is in turn responsible for presenting the SKScene. So unless I am missing something, simply create a segue from the view controller to the GameViewController via the storyboard, and do a performSegue in your initial view controller, when you want to show the game view controller.

Comment: Its updated @KenToh

Comment: For anyone coming at Swift and SpriteKit without massive understanding of casting, types, views, scenes and their various relationships, the point of entry to getting anything to work between these two worlds (UIKit and SpriteKit) is a NIGHTMARE of weirdness @ElTomato. I know. You're probably of the ilk for whom this all makes sense... but as someone in the other group, I know Shane's pain, very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to select your view in ViewController then in identity inspector set it's custom class to "SKView".
it will solve your problem.

[image: SKView]

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene.sks") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure (1) that you have `GameViewController` set to the class name of the view controller scene over the Main.storyboard, (2) that you have `SKView` set to the class name of `View` under Game View Controller